# Как добавить адекватную оптимизацию изображений на WordPress?

Tags: wordpress

подскажите пожалуйста как вы оптимизируйте изображения на WP. Те плагины что есть в топе сжимают их на 10-15% . В то же время те же изображения если я закидываю в онлайн сервисы сжатия - то получаю 80%. Но закидывать вручную не вариант. Есть ли какое то решения?

Comment: Вся графика должна предварительно готовится на дектопе. Я делаю это с пом простой бесплатной и мощной смотрелки https://www.irfanview.com/

Comment: Описанные вами онлайн-сервисы, как правило, продают свои плагины оптимизации графики для различных CMS, включая WP

Comment: Бесплатных решений нет. WP Smash и бесплатных самое то. В целом если вы правильно настроите размеры изображений (я имею ввиду высоту и ширину), то в целом можете хоть в самом лучшем качестве вставлять, уже огромное кол-во памяти вы съекономите